# Excel isblank but automated through vba

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've been wondering if there's a way to automate isblank eg,through a wide selection of rows and columns if there's data in A1 and A2 and A3 is empty then fill A3 with eg."missing". Thanks in advance

I tried using if(A1<>,"T","F") but that would be pain to apply on a big selection, expecting it to automatically look for missing data in eg. A3 ,B3 ,C3...... And check whether there's data in same row in eg A1 , A2 and fill the empty with specific data

Comment: you should add VBA tag also...
And the answer to your Q, -  yes, there are multiple ways to do it in VBA.
If data is very large, VBA may be not the fastest option if it matters

Comment: Could you be more accurate? Are you looking for an Excel formula or a VBA code? For example, why is this `=IF(COUNTA(A1:A2)<2,"Missing","")` in cell `A3` not working for you? Also, how do you plan on using this in VBA? You should add some code to your question to make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than placing "Missing" in the empty cells shade them RED with Conditional Formatting. One Rule can cover a large area.
[image: Conditional Format Rule]

[image: Conditional Format Result]